# Nothing new in inbox despite asking and editing questions

Tags: bug, global-inbox

I **asked** and **edited** questions since this date (Oct. 18 2021) but nothing new appeared in the inbox:

[image: inbox has no items from later than October 18]

This isn't really a problem, but it might be a bug?

Comment: Is there any particular notification you are expecting to be there? Asking questions doesn't generate notifications, and none of your recent questions appear to have interactions from other users on them. So there is nothing to notify you about.

Comment: Are you getting notifications for comments on this post?

Comment: You should be getting notifications for the comments here; see the FAQ for what kind of events should trigger notifications. If you can point out an interaction which *should* generate a notification, please [edit] your question and we'll reopen it.

Comment: @Smitop Indeed, I now can see additional comments.

Comment: @animuson As we can see on my picture, each new question, update or comment appears in the inbox but nothing since the 18/10/2021.

Comment: That's not how it works. *You* posting a question does not spawn a notification. *Other people* commenting on, editing, etc your question does cause notifications.

Comment: @Glorfindel It looks like that the expected behaviour is back !

Comment: @animuson I got it, it's just that I haven't received any notification due to a lack of responses or comments. My own changes never appear in fact.